# How to find which room user joined in socketio python

Tags: python, socket.io

i am working on a project using socketio python. The concept is up to 3 users can join room, when 4th user come a new room will be created and user will joined that room. I did code for this logic which is working find. But on disconnect i need to remove user from the room the user joined, but i didn't figured out how to get user joined room. I need help, new to programming, didn't figured out how to to this.
here is my code:
the assign room will assignroom to user and connect function is the main function which join user to room.

```
def assign_room():
    room_id = None
    global total_rooms
    print(rooms_data)
    for key in rooms_data.keys():
        print(key)
        if rooms_data[key]['isFull'] == False:
            room_id = key
            rooms_data[key]['totalUsers'] += 1
            if(rooms_data[key]['totalUsers'] == 3):
                print("room fill")
                rooms_data[key]['isFull'] = True
            break


    if(room_id == None):
        total_rooms+=1
        print('2ns room in actions')
        rooms_data[total_rooms] = {
            'isFull': False,
            'totalUsers': 1,
            'playerPosition': {}
        }
        return total_rooms

    return room_id



@sio.event
def connect(sid, environ):
    global client_count
    global a_count
    global b_count

    username = environ.get('HTTP_X_USERNAME')
    print('username:', username)
    if not username:
        return False

    with sio.session(sid) as session:
        session['username'] = username
    sio.emit('user_joined', username)

    client_count += 1

    sio.emit('client_count', client_count)

    selected_room = assign_room()
    print(f"Selected room is {selected_room}")
    print(rooms_data)
    sio.enter_room(sid, selected_room)
```

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of your code?

Comment: use some list/dict to keep rooms which user joined - ie. `users[ user_id ] = [room1, room2 ]`. Eventually keep users in rooms - `rooms[ room_id ] = [user1, user_2]`